# Atmel Studio 7 is missing several menu elements

Tags: menu, atmelstudio

I just installed Atmel Studio 7, since I've been having a lot of trouble with Microchip Studio, and a lot of menu options and entire tabs are missing. It looks exactly the same as Microchip Studio, except for it saying "Atmel Studio" instead of "Microchip Studio." Images I've found on the web have parts of the menu and functions that do not exist on my copy. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

[image: Image from the web, showing full-featured Atmel Studio]

[image: Image of my copy, which has fewer menu options]

Comment: Wow, seems like I've discovered something that nobody can fix!